# How can I build Pinry (Python/Django Pinterest Clone) using PyCharm?

Tags: python, django

Before I get started please excuse the complete newbie question (request for dummy steps).  I recently started learning Python and the Django framework using tools like Codecademy and Pluralsight and was hoping to dig into this by running [Pinry](http://getpinry.com/) (a Pinterest clone) using [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), my IDE of choice for Python and work on modifying it with what I've learned so far to see what happens.  Unfortunately, I download the latest version of Pinry and when I try to run it in PyCharm on my local machine I get all sorts of errors.

Here are the steps I take:

1. Python, Django, PyCharm are all installed and configured.
2. Download a new copy of Pinry and open the directory in PyCharm
3. Click on Run - Edit Configuration
4. Click on the + button to add a new configuration and check Run browse, select the Python interpreter (with Django) and click on Fix to enable Django support for the project
5. In the Project - Django settings, add the Django project root, settings and manage script
6. Finally hit alt/option + R and runserver to get the app started
7. At this point I would expect the package to run but instead I get the list of errors below.

Has anyone had any success in running Pinry in PyCharm without making any code modifications?  I am just not sure if these are issues with the package or if its settings in PyCharm that need to be modified to make this work.  Any insights?

### THANK YOU!

```
File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)


File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 176, in run_module
    fname, loader, pkg_name)


File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals

File "/Users/hussein/Desktop/pinry-master/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 279, in execute
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 154, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 151, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Comment: In a file called `settings.py` in a folder named after your project (most likely pinry) there should be a constant variable called `SECRET_KEY`. IT should be set to a bunch of nonsense, what does yours say?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Pycharm btw. You should run your Django app by navigating to the folder that contains `manage.py` and run `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: these errors show up after running runserver

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm "Project settings/Django" specify "settings/development.py" in "settings" field.